# Setting marker on scroling bar

Tags: notebooks

If I have a long notebook with several cells and each one with a title (a separate cell), is there a way to mark the location of these titles on the scroll bar so that I can quickly get to the cell I want?

At the moment what I have to do is scroll and scroll until I get to the cell I need, maybe put a short horizontal stripe on the scroll bar that marks the locations of the titles similar to the way in some other programming softwares the errors and warnings are marked with colors.

So, is there a way to do something like this or maybe another kind of solution?

I tried searching for similar questions but I'm not sure how to phrase the it based on the capabilities of Mathematica. If the question is not understood I'll try and improve my brief explanation.

Comment: Marking scrollbars is 100% not possible but about alternatives, what about this table of contents: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139599/5478

Comment: @Kuba thanks, I'll look into this solution as it suits my problem well enough too.